# How to properly cycle through a text file in python to get username/pw for login?

Tags: python, file, authentication, tkinter

Hey I am having a problem with checking if a username is in a database.Getting the username works fine if the username is in the database now, but how would I check if it wasn't in the database? What I have got cycles through the loop and calls `invalid_details()` each time.

Code:

```
if username.get() == "" or password.get() == "":
    invalid_details()
else:
    for line in open(file_name, "r").readlines():
        login_info = line.strip().split(".")
        if username.get() == login_info[0]:
            if password.get() == login_info[1]:
                print(login_info[0])
                print(login_info[1])
                print(login_info[2])
                print(login_info[3])
                print(login_info[4])
                return True

        if username.get() != login_info[0]:
            invalid_details()
            print("username not found")
```

Comment: How exactly is the username/password file laid out?

Comment: @DanielLavedoniodeLima  username.password.name.surname.email      `def add_account():
    new_password_info = new_password.get()
    new_username_info = new_username.get()
    new_name = first_name.get()
    new_surname = surname.get()
    new_email = email_address.get()

    # write new detail info into file
    file = open(file_name, "a")
    file.write(
        new_username_info + "." + new_password_info + "." + new_name + "." + new_surname + "." + new_email + "\n")
    file.close()`

Comment: Your logic is a bit off. `username.get() in line` does not uniquely identify a line. Compare username with the username field only (`login_info[0]`). If the username does not match, that does not mean `invalid_details()`. You should instead just move to the next line and call `invalid_details()` _after_ the loop (no match was found).

Comment: @hmm Thank you so much!

Comment: @hmm Getting the username works fine if the username is in the database now, but how would I check if it wasn't in the database? What I have got still cycles through the loop and calls `invalid_details()` each time.

Comment: @KevinNisbet Please edit the code in your original post with proper indentation and update the question too if necessary. It's very hard to read blocks of code in comments.

Comment: @hmm Ok, that is the question updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing what `invalid_details()` does, I'm not sure this is *exactly* what you want, but you get the idea.

```
if username.get() == "" or password.get() == "":
    invalid_details()
    return False

for line in open(file_name, "r").readlines():
    login_info = line.strip().split(".")
    if username.get() == login_info[0]:
        if password.get() == login_info[1]:
            print(login_info[0])
            print(login_info[1])
            print(login_info[2])
            print(login_info[3])
            print(login_info[4])
            return True

        invalid_details()
        print("wrong password")
        return False

    # If username did not match, continue to the next line.

# All lines were checked and the username did not match.
invalid_details()
print("username not found")
return False
```